# How do I execute two Mappings at once in SpringBoot by calling only the first mapping first?

Tags: java, spring-mvc

```
@PostMapping(value = "/save")
public String saveRequest(@RequestBody Request request) {
    requestRepo.save(request);

    return "Saved...";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/redirect", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public void method(HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse) {
    httpServletResponse.setHeader("Location", "https://www.google.com");
    httpServletResponse.setStatus(302);
}
```

Is there a way to execute the second mapping automatically after executing the first mapping?
Or a way to mix/make this better?

EDIT: updated redirect mapping method

Comment: I dnt undestand what u mean by "mapping"? Mapping usually means transforming one class into another. You mean to automatize redirecting? and what exactly do u want to combine? Question not clear

Comment: Yes, to automatically redirect me to a certain link after executing postmapping

Comment: What's the point of sending `"Saved..."` if you redirecting the request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@PostMapping(value = "/yourEndpointFromWhichToBeRedirected")
public String saveRequest(@RequestBody Request request) {
    requestRepo.save(request);

    return "redirect:/endpointToWhichToBeRedirectedTo";
}
```

Comment: When I tried to execute it with a simple getmapping API it just returned me this string instead "redirect:/to-be-redirected"

Comment: @GetMapping(value="/requests")
    public String getRequests()
    {
        return "redirect:/to-be-redirected";

    }
This is the example

Comment: you should change `to-be-redirected` to some value that you have in one of your @GetMapping. like for example `"redirect:/save"`. An example in one of my projects https://github.com/asgarov1/cakeFactory/blob/milestone7/src/main/java/com/asgarov/liveproject/cakefactory/controller/BasketController.java

Comment: I don't know what happened but it worked. Thanks Asgarov

Comment: @john555 What you're doing here is redirecting to then be redirected again. That can't be right.

Comment: the values are just placeholders to illustrate a point - OP is supposed to replace them with correct values - update the answer